# Load Balancing without connecting to a server

Tags: load-balancing

I am having trouble verifying load balancing on fortigate 501e v6.0. I do not have a server to connect to but I tried creating a Virtual Server via the GUI and ping the external port. But when I enter the *Load Balance Monitor* on the GUI, nothing appears.  Would anyone have any suggestions on how to get load balancing to work?

Comment: Your load balancing is going to be per flow, not per packet. You are going to need to create multiple flows.

Comment: can you explain little more . i am confusing about your question